# unable to addSubView

Tags: ios, ios5

I have this method in my main view controller:

```
-(void)showDialog {    
    if (stopDialogController == nil)
        stopDialogController = [[StopDialogController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StopDialog" bundle:nil WithStop:@"CLAS"];
    if (stopDialogController)
        [stopDialogController presentWithSuperview:self.view withStopName:@"Evan Kimia"]; 
}
```

that gets executed fine if i call it from within that same view controller with [self showDialog], but if i pass the pointer of this main class to another view controller it gets executed but the view doesnt get added as a subview of the main view controller like it should and i have no idea why. Below is the presentWithSuperview method:

```
- (void)presentWithSuperview:(UIView *)superview withStopName:stopName;
{
    NSLog(@"present w/ superview called.");
    [superview addSubview:self.view];
    stopNameLabel.text=stopName;

}
```

Comment: Please confirm that superview is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small example project and I cannot reproduce the problems you are experiencing. In my minimal project I have 3 view controllers: MainViewController, SecondViewController and ThirdViewController. I will paste the relevant methods below, please check for differences between your project and this example, also it could be a good idea to post more code.

**MainViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
    thirdViewController.mainViewController = self;
    [thirdViewController showDialogIndirect];
}

-(void)showDialog {    
    if (secondViewController == nil)
        secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil WithStop:@"CLAS"];
    if (secondViewController)
        [secondViewController presentWithSuperview:self.view withStopName:@"Evan Kimia"]; 
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil WithStop:(NSString *)stopString {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self){
        // init here
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)presentWithSuperview:(UIView *)superView withStopName:(NSString *)stopName {
    NSLog(@"present %@ with superview %@ and stopName %@", self, superView, stopName);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [superView addSubview:self.view];
}
```

**ThirdViewController**

```
-(void) showDialogIndirect {
    [self.mainViewController showDialog];
}
```